# Introduction to LaTeX and Markup

Tags: tutorials

I've got interest from someone in LaTeX, but she's not a computer person. She is smart, very smart, but not a computer person. i.e. She didn't know that typing something on the command line ran a program, she thought they were all part of the command line. Is there a really basic introduction to LaTeX and markup in general for her? Something that will start from basic concepts, and build from there, without going into 'here are a zillion editor options and different versions of LaTeX' like the wikibook does? I think the wikibook is a great resource once you understand what is going on, but I'd like an introduction to explain the basic concept, perhaps with some very minimal examples?

Comment: [Not so short introduction to LaTeX](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) which can also be found by `texdoc lshort`

Comment: @cmhughes That looks good, but it needs to be updated for pdflatex desperately. Also needs to explain what markup is.

Comment: I have found that the tag [tag:tutorials] exist which, I hope, covers what you meant by [tag:introduction].

Comment: @tohecz Works for me

Comment: This previous question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex?rq=1 was in the 'Related' section. It may be worth a look, if you haven't already.

Comment: I think that the best for beginners is a small tutorial like [Getting to Grips with LaTeX](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex)

Answer (score 4):

I've learned with this awesome manual and I think it's exactly what you want.

http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf

If you are a Mac user, for me TexShop is the best option.

http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/

For PC Texniccenter is a very good option and it has a very simple installation guide.

http://www.texniccenter.org